# Apache Rewrite Rule Conditional

Tags: apache, renaming

I am completely new to Apache and development in general. Does anyone know how i can do the following in the same apache `.htaccess` ?

Convert 
`http:// www. example .com/username` TO `http: //www.example.com/page1.php?s=username`

And convert

`http:// www .example.com/username/events` TO `http:// www.example .com/events.php?s=username`

And convert

`http: //www. example .com/username/EV134` TO `http: //www. example . com/event.php?e=EV134&s=username`

And convert

`http: // www. example.com/username/134` TO `http: //www.example.com/page2.php?p=134&s=username`

I just got no idea how to even start. I did obviously read alot of posts and tutorials but it just all goes over my head, especially the documentation on Apache site.

Comment: Show your code you've been trying.

Comment: On a side note, implementing URL routing via mod_rewrite in .htaccess files is most definitly a bad idea, although a very common one, because it is going to end up as an unreadable mess, and also because performance will suffer, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/howto/htaccess.html#when

Comment: interesting then what should i read about please